# In R, how do I concatenate multiple columns within a list of lists

Tags: r, list, concatenation

I have a function in R which returns a list with N columns each of M rows of multiple types - date, numeric and char.  I am using sapply to create multiple copies of these lists, which then end up in a top level list.  I would like to concatenate the underlying lists together to produce a single list of N columns and M * number of list rows.

I've been trying different combinations of do.call, sapply, rbind, c, etc, but I think I'm missing something pretty fundamental.  Below is a simple script that mimics the problem and shows the desired outcome.  I've used 3 variables here, but the number of variables is arbitrary.

```
# Set up test function
testfun <- function(varName) 
{
  currDate = seq(as.Date('2018-12-31'), as.Date('2019-01-10'), "days")
  t1 = runif(11)
  t2 = runif(11)
  groupNum = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,6))
  varName = rep(varName, 11)

  dataout= data.frame(currDate, t1, t2, groupNum, varName)
}  

# create 3 test variables and run the data
varNames = c('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
tmp = sapply(varNames, testfun)

# I would like it to look like the following, but for any given number of variables
desiredAnswer <- rbind(as.data.frame(tmp[,1]),as.data.frame(tmp[,2]),as.data.frame(tmp[,3]))
```

The final answer will later be used to create a data table and feed ggplot with the varName as facets. 
 I'm happy to use any method to get the desired results, there's no reason the function needs to produce a list instead of say a data.frame.  I'm certain I'm doing something dumb, any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `lapply` instead of `sapply` and then `do.call(rbind, tmp)`?